# How to bond/pair a bluetooth device programmatically in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth

Is it possible to bond/pair a bluetooth device programmatically in **Flutter**? I don't want to show the message to enter the pin. Instead I want to hardcode it and get paired in a single button tap.
I am using **flutter_bluetooth_serial** package to search and connect bluetooth devices.

It is showing alert box to enter the pin if I use the following code.

```
 await FlutterBluetoothSerial
 .instance
 .bondDeviceAtAddress(deviceAddress);
```

When I use like below, It is not connecting and getting timeout error.

```
 await FlutterBluetoothSerial
 .instance
 .bondDeviceAtAddress(deviceAddress, pin: "1234")
```

If it is not possible with this package, please suggest a solution in native (**Kotlin**), So that I can use platform channel.

Comment: Hello
I'm having similar issue. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: not yet, still waiting for a better solution

Comment: Use Nearby Messages API. It supports Android to Android, iOS to iOS, and Android to iOS communications. But it requires internet connection. 

Sadly there is no package, so I made one. I can't share it with you because it is the property of our company. I think you can make it yourself. it took me about 1 week of work

Good luck